# Webpack compile scss to css file which is minified

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I am getting started with webpack and I am having hard time configuring it so it could compile a scss file which is like this:

main.scss

```
@import 'scss/variables.scss'
@import 'scss/..scss'
// more stuff
```

here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: [
        './assets/js/main.js',
        ],
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/[name].min.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['babel-preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

I tried many online tutorials but I am getting bunch of errors. The above compiles but I just want to add `main.scss` so it compiles to `main.min.css` in dist folder and is already compressed.

Comment: So what I'm understand right now is you just want to compile scss to css then minify it and dont want to compile js ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#advanced-configuration-example

Comment: @TonyNgo I just need this file to include the css and compiles it too. I use codekit and though webpack is the same thing, codekit compiles my sass and minifies my js

Comment: No you cant do that because wepback need to compile css that you include in your js file. If you want to only compile scss file you can use sass cli